# Using hardhat to fork a node but getting 'Missing Trie Node'

Tags: hardhat, nodejs, forks

Im using hardhat to fork a node in the command line.

```
cmd> npx hardhat node --fork https://therpcnodehere.com
```

After about 10 minutes or so the fork starts responding to requests with 'missing trie node'

I thought that this error would only happen if attempting to pin a block but im not specifying a block number so assume it should always execute with the latest block?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with that command you're pinning the 'latest' block. So you need an archival node also for this case if you plan on running the fork for long amounts.

From the point of view of the node, you're querying data 10 minutes old. As you know, a normal node doesn't keep all its state history. 10 minutes is around 64 blocks of history, which is apparently the amount your rpc node is keeping.